# Casating from Derived to Base, ambiguouty

Tags: inheritance, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast

Suppose we have

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){}
};

class Derived: public virtual Base
{};

class Derived_Left: public Derived
{};

class Derived_Right: public Derived
{};

class Bottom: public Derived_Left, public Derived_Right
{};
```

//let discuss to cases

//case 1:

```
void foo()
{
    Base *bptr = new Bottom;
    Derived *dPtr = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(bptr);//dptr == 0
}
```

// case 2:

```
void goo()
{
    Bottom *bptr = new Bottom;
    Derived *ddtr = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(bptr); // ERROR
}
```

//main.cpp: In function ‘void goo()’:

//main.cpp:36:49: error: ‘Derived’ is an ambiguous base of ‘Bottom’

```
int main()
{
}
```

So, why code is compiled in case of

```
Base* bptr = new Bottom;
```

and not in case of

```
Bottom* bptr = new Bottom;
```

Comment: First i want to mention that i compile it first time under ubuntu g++. And it gave me that error. But at home i tried to comile it under windows/visual stuio 2012 and it gave me just an warning                    warning C4540: dynamic_cast used to convert to inaccessible or ambiguous base; run-time test will fail ('Bottom *' to 'Derived *')

Answer (score -1):

You already asked the same Question. So I'll answer short:
It's the diamond problem.
In the case, your casting an pointer of Type Base, to derived,  the Base class just knows the in this case unique child class. 
But from the view of an object of type Bottom, its ambiguous, you want to be working with the derived class which is parent of Derived_left or of Derived_Right.